# Is it possible to create/work with a non-paralleized file in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

we always talk about how much faster will be if we use hadoop to paralleized our data and programme . 
I would like to know is that possible to keep a small file in one specific dataNode(not paralleized)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and show that you made some research effort, in the relevant documentation and in other Stack Overflow questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> possible to keep a small file in one specific dataNode

HDFS will try to split any file into HDFS blocks. The datanodes don't store the entire file, nor should you attempt to store on a particular one. Let Hadoop manage the data-locality.

Your file will be replicated 3 times by default in Hadoop for fault tolerance anyway.

If you have small files (less than the HDFS block size, 64 or 128MB, depending on the Hadoop version), then you probably [shouldn't be using Hadoop](https://aadrake.com/command-line-tools-can-be-235x-faster-than-your-hadoop-cluster.html). If you need parallelized processing, start with multi-threading. If you actually need distributed processes, my recommendation nowadays would be Spark or Flink, not Hadoop (MapReduce).

If you want this, seems like you want [object storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_storage), not block storage